# Do I risk cropping international characters when I set includeFontPadding to false?

Tags: android, textview, user-experience

In order to get rid of th extra space on top of a TextView, I have the solution to set the `includeFontPadding` property to false.

The project is due to be internationalized in many languages including Chinese, Japanese and other non-Latin scripts.
Is `includeFontPadding`'s reserved space guaranteed to be blank or do I risk to crop any tall characters by setting the property to false?